# Can't resolve all parameters for firestore2

Tags: nodejs, angular, firebase

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto en angular con firebase, estoy metiendo un servicio para meter documentos a mi base de datos

firestore.service.ts

```
import { Firestore, collection, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { UserI } from '../models/users.model';
import { addDoc, deleteDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirestoreService {

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }

  async crearUsuario(user : UserI){
    let col = collection(this.firestore,'Usuarios');
    const docRef = await addDoc(col, user);

    return docRef.id;
  }
  obtenerDocumentos(path: string){
    let col = collection(this.firestore, path);
    return collectionData(col,{idField:'id'});
  }
  borrarDoc(id: string, path: string){
    let docRef = doc(this.firestore, path +'/'+id)
    return deleteDoc(docRef);
  }
}
```

y le puse en los providers en el app.component.ts debido a que no tengo el app.module, saben que le podria hacer para resolverlo

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RegisterComponent } from "./pages/register/register.component";

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import { FirestoreService } from "./services/firestore.service";
import { Firestore, FirestoreModule, getFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  providers: [Firestore],
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"], // Corregido a 'styleUrls' y debe ser un array.
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "develaware.com";
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCzi_PropLAWTowzhfmRrpbI1B-Lc0l-Rs",
      authDomain: "develaware-228cc.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://develaware-228cc-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    })
  }

}
```

Pero cuando lo corro me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le quito ese provider me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este error me sale cuando entro al register component, el primer error sale cuando quiero correr el proyecto,adjunto tambien el registercomponent para mas info

```
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserI } from '../../models/users.model';
import { LoginService } from '../login/login.service';
import { FirestoreService } from '../../services/firestore.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    NgFor,
  ],
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrl: './register.component.css'
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterComponent {

  datos: UserI = {
    uid: '',
    nombre: '',
    correo: '',
    password: '',
    perfil: 'visitante'
  }

  constructor(private loginService:LoginService, private firestore: FirestoreService){}

  async registrar(form: NgForm){
    this.datos.correo = form.value.email
    this.datos.nombre = form.value.name
    const password = form.value.password
    this.datos.password = null
    // console.log(email, nombre, password)
    const res = await this.loginService.registerUser(this.datos.correo, password)
    .catch(
      error=>{
          console.log('error' + error)
      })
    if(res){
      console.log(res)
      await this.firestore.crearUsuario(this.datos)
      .catch(
        error=>{
            console.log('error' + error)
        })
    }

    // this.loginService.login(email, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Prueba usando `firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);` en lugar de llamarlo en el constructor, bien reinstalando con `npm i @angular/fire@17.0.0-next.0` ya que AngularFire todavía no sale para Angular 17 (si checas en npm desde Angular 14 están en la versión 7.4) o creando un archivo de configuración para eso como indican en esta pregunta [firebase - Installing Angular/Fire into Angular 17 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77502439/installing-angular-fire-into-angular-17).